# Understanding conditional probability - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to remember all the probability bits I did in school! I think the below is correct, is it possible to help me out - have I gone wrong anywhere?

**Formula for conditional probability:**
P(B|A) = P(A and B) / P(A)

**which can be re-written as**
P(B|A) = P(A∩B) / P(A).

if we have 5 marbles in a bag. 2 are black and 3 are red. The chance of getting a black marble in the first selection is 2/5. When we select the next marble, we have now only got 4 marbles, of which 1 is black (because we have removed one in our first selection). So, the probability of selecting a black is 1/4.

**formula:** P(B|A) = (1/4 * 2/5) / P(2/5) = (0.25 * 0.4)/0.4 gives us 0.25

I also wonder... as I already knew that the probabiltiy of B given A was 0.25, what was the point of the formula?

I am also not clear what this formula seeks to find out: p(A∩B) = p(A) * p(B|A) = 0.4*0.25 = 0.1 chance

if I know that the chance of getting B given A is 0.25, how do I know the likelihood of getting A and then B given A?

Comment: I think you confused $P(B|A)$ and $P(B)$, also $P(AB) \neq P(A)P(B)$ unless $A$ and $B$ are independent (which is not the case here). Correct version would be $P(AB) = \frac{2!3!}{5!} = 0.1$ and then P(B|A) = 0.1/0.4 = 0.25

Comment: Thanks, but surely P(A)*P(B) is the same as P(AB)? - and if I know that the chance of getting B given A is 0.25, how do I know the likelihood of getting A and then B given A?

Comment: Why? No, $P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|\bar{A})P(\bar{A}) = 0.25*0.4+0.5*0.6 = 0.4$ hence $P(A)P(B) = 0.16 \neq 0.1 = P(AB)$

Comment: where did that formula come from? what does it do? what does p(A∩B) = p(A) * p(B|A) do? if I know that the chance of getting B given A is 0.25, how do I know the likelihood of getting A and then B given A?

Comment: It is law of total probability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: We want to calculate $P(A\cap B)$ where $A$ denotes the event that the first marble is black and $B$ denotes the event that the second marble is black. Then it is handsome to write $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)$. The first factor is of course $\frac25$ and the second - denoting the probability that the second marble will be black if the first was - is of course $\frac14$ (one black is left among 4 marbles in total). So we find: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)=\frac25\frac14=\frac1{10}$ and we are ready. A proper and elegant way to calculate $P(A\cap B)$, right?

Comment: Thanks @drhab, so I need to use conditional probability in conjunction with this multiplication rule to find the answer. Thanks for that!